# Does static std::map instatiation in method of a class call constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, std, undefined-behavior, stdmap

I have a doubt, i have a class, we can say "a" that have a method "b" that in the body instatiate a static std::map. The question is:

***the the following code ensure that the constructor of the std::map is called? Or we have an undefined behaviour?***

**a.h**

```
class a {
public:
    void b();
};
```

**a.cpp**

```
void a::b(){
    static std::map<int,int> mapB;
    bool notFound = mapB.find(0) == mapB.end();
    std::cout << "notFound: " << notFound << std::endl;
}
```

In my case this code works and the output is:

```
notFound: 1
```

But it is correct? Or is only a case of an Undefined Behaviour?

Another doubt is if i have a map with a class instead of a basic type, is the same thing?
I report a sample code:

**c.h**

```
class c {
public:
    int i;
};
```

**a.h**

```
class a {
public:
    void b();
};
```

**a.cpp**

```
void a::b(){
    static std::map<int,c> mapB;
    bool notFound = mapB.find(0) == mapB.end();
    std::cout << "notFound: " << notFound << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `static` local variables will *always* be constructed (and initialized) in the first call to the function.

Comment: so in my case is constructed and initialized when the '''find()''' in called?

Comment: No, when the function **`b`** is first called. The `static` variables will be constructed and initialized before the main body of the function is executed. But only on the *first* call to the `b` funciton.

Comment: ok, now is all clear so my code is ever correct.

Comment: why wouldnt it call the constructor? I dont know how to get a `std::map` without calling its constructor

Answer (score 2):

> But it is correct?

Yes.

> Or is only a case of an Undefined Behaviour?

No.

Default initialising a non-trivial class such as instance of standard map calls the default constructor of the class.

> Another doubt is if i have a map with a class instead of a basic type, is the same thing?

This doesn't matter for initialisation of the map.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the constructor is executed the first time that you call `b()`.  This is specified in [8.8.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4):

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization.